# Admin backup panel troubles

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have just met a curious trouble. When I log to my live store admin panel and go to System>Backups, there is not any backups listed available while there are several backups in the var/backups directory when I connect to the SFTP. Even the panel display is strange...

My Filezilla Screenshot with backup files on the var/bacups directory :
[image]

The Backups section from the admin panel of my local development store (eveything is OK):
[image]

The Backups section from the admin panel of my live store (nothing is OK): [image]

Everything was fine until two days ago when the backups listing disapeared...I only work on a local version of my store, not on the live one so nothing has been changed on my live store.

Any clue of what happens and how to correct that bug ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you check the permission is properly setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : the probleme came from a backup file which name was disturbing for Magento 2. I just erase that file and everyhting is back ok.